# Modal not getting refresh with new data

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have a page where all data is loaded dynamically from a database and displayed in divs. On every div there is button named `View`. On click of this button I call a method: `onclick="getdetails(this)"`. This method creates a modal dynamically with data and it is working completely fine.

```
function getdetails(par) {
    var modaldiv = '';
    var maincontent = '';
    var htourid = document.getElementById("htourid" + par.id).value;
    var hadultprice = document.getElementById("hadultprice" + par.id).value;
    var hchildprice = document.getElementById("hchildprice" + par.id).value;
    var hdescription = document.getElementById("hdescription" + par.id).value;
    var htourname = document.getElementById("htourname" + par.id).value;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xxxxxxxxxxxx" + htourid,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data) {
            var rowcount = 1;
            for (var i = 0; i < data.GetToursDetailsimagesResult.TourImages.length; i++) {
                if (rowcount == 1) {
                    maincontent += '<div class="item active">' +
                        '<img src="' + data.GetToursDetailsimagesResult.TourImages[i].ImagePath + '" alt=""/>' +
                        '</div>';
                } else {
                    maincontent += '<div class="item">' +
                        '<img src="' + data.GetToursDetailsimagesResult.TourImages[i].ImagePath + '" alt=""/>' +
                        '</div>';
                }
                rowcount++;
            }
            modaldiv = '<div id="modal-package" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">' +
                '<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">' +
                '<div class="modal-content">' +
                '<div class="modal-header">' +
                '<a  class="close" href = "Tours_and_Activities.aspx" aria-hidden="true">&times;</a>' +
                '<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tabs">' +
                '<li class="active"><a href="#modal-tabs-package"><i class="gi gi-package"></i>Details</a></li>' +
                '</ul>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-body">' +
                '<div class="tab-content">' +
                '<div class="tab-pane active" id="modal-tabs-package">' +
                '<h1 class="h2"><strong style="margin-left: 16px;">' +
                '<asp:Label ID="lbl_tourdetails_tour_name" Text="' + htourname + '" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong></h1>' +
                '<input type="hidden" id="htourid" value="' + htourid + '" />' +
                '<div class="col-lg-7">' +
                '<div id="project-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">' +
                '<div id="divimages" class="carousel-inner text-center">' +
                maincontent +
                '</div>' +
                '<a class="left carousel-control" href="#project-carousel" data-slide="prev">' +
                '<span>' +
                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>' +
                '</span>' +
                '</a>' +
                '<a class="right carousel-control" href="#project-carousel" data-slide="next">' +
                '<span>' +
                '<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>' +
                '</span>' +
                '</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<asp:Label ID="lbldescription" Text="' + hdescription + '" runat="server"></asp:Label>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '<div class="modal-footer">' +
                '<h4 class="pull-left"><span class="text-muted"><b>Adult Price: </b></span><strong class="text-primary">' +
                '<asp:Label ID="lbl_viewadultprice" Text="' + hadultprice + '" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong>/</h4>' +
                '<h4 class="pull-left"><span class="text-muted"><b>Child Price: </b></span><strong class="text-primary">' +
                '<asp:Label ID="lbl_viewchildprice" Text="' + hchildprice + '" runat="server"></asp:Label></strong></h4>' +
                '<br />' +
                '<br />' +
                '<button type="button" class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-success" onclick="Open_Addtocart_view(this)" style="background-color: #7DC402;"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</button>' +
                '<a  class="btn btn-effect-ripple btn-danger" style="background-color: #C43902;" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>';
            $("#modaldiv").append(modaldiv);
            $('#modal-package').modal('show');
        }
    });
}
```

The problem is once I click on any divs 'View' button for the first time it goes on displaying the same data in modal even after I click any other view details button. If I refresh the page it displays new data, but then again the same issue goes on.

Can anyone help me find out what the problem is and how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried to empty the content of the previously displayed modal using `$("#modaldiv").empty()`?

Comment: No i didn't try this, ill try this and get back to you 

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Thanks a lot @RoryMcCrossan 
it worked like a charm!!

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hi its prashant here , i have another query sir kindly help me out with that

I have function that has ajax post , inside that ajax post i am calling another ajax funtion that return me some value , but problem is inside tht loop the another function is getting executed only once and i am getting this error





XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: You would be best to start a new question for that one.

Comment: i have already asked a question , i want you to please look at it once please 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35504736/function-is-only-working-once-in-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to empty the previous content of the modal before you `append()` the new HTML. You can do this by using the `empty()` method. Try this:

```
$("#modaldiv").empty().append(modaldiv);
```